# Titanium iOS auto restart application in background once swiped off from background

Tags: ios7, ibeacon, titanium-alloy

I am working in an application that detects any Beacons nearby and gives and alert in the form of local notifications for iOS. I used TiBeacons library for titanium which did the work but I am right now stuck with an issue where I need to keep the Application running even when the user swipes off the application from background.

I was able to make it work in background which is the paused state,but is it possible to make it restart itself in the background when the user swipes the app from the background processes running,maybe with a delay if not promptly?? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to restart application after user removed it from a memory. This would be huge security bridge allowing developers to do lots of evil things to customers' devices.

You can run your code only when app is in foreground and background but never when it's killed.

You can try activate your app by receiving notification from [Apple Notification Center Service](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/AppleNotificationCenterServiceSpecification/Specification/Specification.html):

> The purpose of the Apple Notification Center Service (ANCS) is to give Bluetooth accessories (that connect to iOS devices through a Bluetooth low-energy link) a simple and convenient way to access many kinds of notifications that are generated on iOS devices.

Comment: @daniula-- I am kindof confused with that answer as there are many applications thar does get you local notifications even when swiped off from background. iBeacon app from radius networks for example does work.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand your question but iOS app can be in [5 different states](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html) and when somebody swipes it out from background it goes through quick suspended state and than not running. The only way to get up running again is through receiving notification. I'll update my answer with related link.

Comment: Thanks for your response. This is what I am looking for but I am confused on how to implement the same using titanium as I need to show a local notification when a bluetooth activated iphone device is nearby to the application eventhough the application is swiped off from the background.

Comment: CoreLocation absolutely can launh an app into the background on ibeacon detection, even after being swiped off the task manager.

Comment: The library I am using is already using it. https://github.com/jbeuckm/TiBeacons/blob/master/Classes/OrgBeuckmanTibeaconsModule.m

Comment: @davidgyoung : Application works fine when user adds the application in background and beacon comes nearby,I get the local notification.But the issue is when,I swipe the application off from the background,thats when I don't get any notifications :(

Comment: Do you have iOS7.1?  The ability to detect after the task is killed was only added then.

Answer (score 1):

The ability to detect iBeacons after the app was killed in the task switcher was only added in iOS 7.1.  Also, I believe this functionality requires that beacon monitoring be set up with the app's main `AppDelegate` object as the `CoreLocation` delegate.  I do not know much about Titanium, but glancing at the source, it appears it does not do this, and instead uses a different class as the `CoreLocation` delegate.  This may explain why this does not work for you.

If my suspicion is true, you would not be able to detect after the app is killed using an unmodified version of that library.

Since I am not a Titanium expert, it would be best if someone who knows more about it could confirm or refute my suspicion.

Comment: Yeah I am using iOS 7.1. Actually the problem with titanium is that the build files are created at runtime and the build created using titanium doesn't seem to have much info on where the classes related to coreLocation are which I couldnt find doing a global search.hence I am not able to do any sort of debugging either , the base code is written in javascript :(